# My variables aren't working, keep recieving 'expression result unused' error

Tags: c, variables, cs50

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to make a right aligned triangle of # marks. I'm receiving an error from my variable 'space'. Could someone tell me why I am receiving this error?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_height(void);
int lineno;
int column_fill;
int main(void)
{
    int height = get_height();
    int space = height;
    for (lineno = 1; lineno <= height; lineno++ )
        {
        for (space; space > 0; space--)
            {
            printf(".");
            }
            for (column_fill = 1; column_fill <= lineno; column_fill++)
                {
                printf("#");
                }
            printf("\n");
            }
}

int get_height(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }while(height < 0 || height > 9);

    return height;
}
```

The error I'm recieving is:
mario.c:13:14: error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value] for (space; space > 0; space--) ^~~~~ 1 error generated. : recipe for target 'mario' failed make: *** [mario] Error 1

Comment: It would help if you gave us the exact error including the line number. Is it this: `for (space;`? What did you intend that to do? Did you mean to initialise `space` to some value there? I see you have `space = height;` outside all the loops. But the inner loop changes `space` and is not reset when that loop runs again in the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: The error I am recieving is: mario.c:13:14: error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
        for (space; space > 0; space--)
             ^~~~~
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'mario' failed
make: *** [mario] Error 1

Comment: I want the space = height to initialise the starting value of space. Then, I want the for loop to print "." for the amount = to 'space' and then decrease by 1.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and terrible at explaining myself.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a hint for your future questions: Please add relevant information like the error message you got, into the question. They are barely readable in comments. For this purpose you can update your question using the `edit` button below your question and add the messages or any other additional information.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm still learning how this works.

Comment: One hint to make your code a little more readable is to place the open and closing braces ( '{' and '}' ) at the same indent level as the "for" on your "for" loops.  That helps to frame the for loop content visually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for (space; space > 0; space--)`, the first `space` does not do anything, and the compiler is warning you about this.

Commonly, the first item in a `for` statement is either an expression that does something, such as an assignment `space = height`, or a declaration of one or more objects to be used in the loop, such as `int space = height`. Change your code to one of these, and the compiler will stop complaining.

You likely should use the latter and remove the earlier separate declaration of `space` because:

- You need to reset `space` each time this loop starts.
- It is preferable to keep declarations as local as possible, to avoid opportunities for mistakes.